# Compile a Java program on the server right before a User downloads the program

Tags: java, compilation, jit, on-the-fly

I did a quick search and could not find anything on this topic.  I am not even sure if this is possible, but I am curious.

Is it possible to compile a Java program on a server right before a user downloads the program.  The application that I can think of for this would be to modify a program's source code on the fly before a user downloads it.  This could be helpful in a setup where the program is modified based on user input or settings on a website and those changes are hard baked into the program so what they download is a stand alone program that is customized and fully portable.  The other application I thought of would be if each user were to use a different feature combination in a program so it is compiled only with the feature set they need/want on the fly.

I have a few programs ideas that I could test this out with, but this is mostly an academic thought and curiosity of mine.

So long story short, does anyone know of any technologies that could make a system like this work?

Comment: Are you looking for some kind of psychic server to know when the user's about to download the program?

Comment: Even if it's possible, I'd suggest just packaging the app per-user and simply modifying some configuration file (JNLP is perfect for this!)

Comment: @Falmarri, no more along the lines of a user picking a feature set on a web form and then the program is "baked" so it is specific to their configuration.  And yes I can do this all with configuration files and such, but as I said this question was asked out of curiosity as a "is this possible" not a "I want to do this"

Comment: @Joachim Sauer, Yes I definitely need to look more into JNLP.  Thinking about that and Java Web Start is what originally spawned my curiosity, what I am thinking of I may very well be able to accomplish it using JNLP.  I definitely need to look more into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written a library using the Compile API (comes with Java 6) to compile code in ememory but I would suggest you don't need to pre-generate code as anything you can do with generated code you can do with dynamic code.  There can be a slight performance advantage, but I suggest you try doing what you need with dynamic code (i.e. code with loops, if statements and reflection) to do what your generated code would do first as this is alot simpler and likely to do what you want.

Even if you must have generated code, it is useful to write the code in a non-generated form first so you are clear as to what you need the code to do.

Comment: I agree with you completely, that part of my question was purely academic, I was not sure if it was possible.  I am mostly interested in only compiling features the user would need on the fly.  In an interest to keep the program size as small as possible, which is important more for the Java Web Start implementation so the program can download and start to execute as quickly and seamlessly as possible.

Comment: Generated code tends to be much larger than the same dynamic code. (To the point where you can test the limits of the compiler or JVM) It would be very difficult to ensure it is smaller.

Comment: Im not really thinking of generating code.  More along the lines of say you have a set of features but most users will only use a subset of those features.  So I would have the server compile the program with only the subset of features rather than all 10.  Granted this would vary wildly on an implementation by implementation basis, but it could be useful in some cases.

Comment: You can place the features in different jars and have the client only download the jars its needs. I haven't used it but you can build an index which says which packages/classes are in which jars and it should workout which jars to download for you. If not you can do this yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, it's possible.

Just let the download link point to some script, that compiles / packages the source and sends back the result. This can be implemented in, for instance PHP, in just a few lines of code. It's quite similar to captchas: On-the-fly generated unique data, retrieved through a URL.

I myself have thought about this idea for protocol obfuscation purposes and for "software registration key algorithm" generation.

I would however recommend you to factor out the parts which you want to be recompiled into a separate class / set of classes, compile only these, and package it with the rest of the (already compiled) program upon request.

Comment: hmm, I was hoping that was possible.  I use PHP as my main server language, is there something built into PHP that would allow me to compile Java.  I have search around for it and can not find much on the topic.  I would assume that I would need to have a Java compiler installed on the server.  Are there any java-compilers that are easy to implement on a server, or even assuming that I have one installed, how would I invoke that from PHP?

Comment: Also I like your recommendation about having a base program that is compiled and only compile the features that may be variable.  That is a good point.  I probably would have arrived at that solution eventually, but its nice to have that idea from the start.